# Is there a way to scale SCNNode as per its parent SCNView's frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I am having a 3D model loaded using a collada file on a `Scenekit` project using `ObjC` language. I would like to achieve dynamic scaling of the 3d model i.e a `SCNNode` just like as `AutoLayout` applies to any `UIControl` with constraints applied on them.

I want `SCNNode` scaled to the factor as that of its parent `SCNView`'s scaling factor without clipping any parts of 3D model.

If it's possible how do I achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

There is no convenience to do that automatically.
You'll have to place the camera according to its field of view and the object's dimensions.

See [How to calculate the z-distance of a camera to view an image at 100% of its original scale in a 3D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533135/how-to-calculate-the-z-distance-of-a-camera-to-view-an-image-at-100-of-its-orig)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something but I don't see why you have to manipulate a camera.

Any SCNNode has the property of `.scale`, why not use that?

`geometryNode.scale = SCNVector3(x:xscale,y:yscale,z:zscale)`

Comment: What is the equivalent in Obj C ?